How to properly place lines from Figma to CSS
I have 2 lines that I want to place on my website on the background. I draw an example lines on a 1920x1620 page. I want these 2 red lines to be on the background. But when I try to copy the sizes from Figma (W and H to left and top) I get the wrong placement at all.
Here's the way my lines look like in Figma:
Line1
Line2
And here's how they being displayed in my browser:
result
index.html:
   <div class="background">
                <img src="assets/Line1.png" alt="line_1"
                                     class="line_1">
                <img src="assets/Line2.png" alt="line_2"
                                     class="line_2">
   </div>

styles.css:
.background img {
    position: absolute;
}

.line_1 {
    left: 1291pt;
    top: 417pt;
}

.line_2 {
    left: 1315pt;
    top: 671pt;
}

How do I resolve it? Thanks!

Honestly, use an SVG. CSS is way underpowered for this sort of design.

Absolute positioning is a very poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out LearnLayout.com

It would also be helpful if we could see what this is supposed to look like and have the actual images to use. Frankly though, if these are supposed to be a background, why not use background-image?

@Paulie_D thank you for response! Do you mean that I should just download the group of images from Figma as an SVG file and place it as a background-image? Will it become responsive this way?

It can be, depends how you implement it.

ohh thank you so much! By the way, if my final SVG is 1920x1600 but my screen size is 1920x1020 and I have a very long content on my page like 1920x2520, is it possible to scroll the background until 1600px height and after that scroll only the content?

I think so, I'd have to check. It really depends on what you are using these lines for. A proper [mcve] with the actual images in another question seems indicated

@Paulie_D Thank you for your help, I think this question can be closed and yes, I think it's the theme for a new question, so please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78776161/scrollable-hero-image
