Scrollable hero-image
I have made a simple background in Figma (1920x1600) and I want to place it as a hero image. But the problem is that the screen resolution can be 1920x800. I also want to place some content on the page. I want when user scrolls down the background would scroll until 1600 height and then it would scroll only the content.
Here's the simple example:
I have an image from Figma image
then I import it as PNG export output
I wrote a CSS script to use it as a background:


body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.background_container {
  background-color: #444444;
  background-image: url("https://i.sstatic.net/mL8LVRMD.png");
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  position: absolute;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="background_container">

  </div>

  <p class="txt"> Example1 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example2 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example3 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example4 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example5 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example6 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example7 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example8 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example9 </p>

  <p class="txt"> Example1 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example2 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example3 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example4 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example5 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example6 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example7 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example8 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example9 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example1 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example2 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example3 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example4 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example5 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example6 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example7 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example8 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example9 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example1 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example2 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example3 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example4 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example5 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example6 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example7 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example8 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example9 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example1 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example2 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example3 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example4 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example5 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example6 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example7 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example8 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example9 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example1 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example2 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example3 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example4 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example5 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example6 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example7 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example8 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example9 </p>

</body>

</html>



and when I try to open this page I can see the top part of it but it does not let me to scroll it down even with the content:
result

This is the closest I could do... hope it helped you.
(make full screen to see the result)


    document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      const backgroundContainer = document.querySelector('.background_container');
      const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
      const maxScroll =1600-window.innerHeight;

      if (scrollTop <= maxScroll) {
        backgroundContainer.style.transform = `translateY(${scrollTop}px)`;
      } else {
        backgroundContainer.style.transform = `translateY(${maxScroll}px)`;
      }
    });
  body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
}

.background_container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1600px; 
  background-image: url("https://i.sstatic.net/mL8LVRMD.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  z-index: -1;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="background_container"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <p class="txt">Example1</p>
    <p class="txt">Example2</p>
    <p class="txt">Example3</p>
    <p class="txt">Example4</p>
    <p class="txt">Example5</p>
    <p class="txt">Example6</p>
    <p class="txt">Example7</p>
    <p class="txt">Example8</p>
    <p class="txt">Example9</p>
    <p class="txt">Example1</p>
    <p class="txt">Example2</p>
    <p class="txt">Example3</p>
    <p class="txt">Example4</p>
    <p class="txt">Example5</p>
    <p class="txt">Example6</p>
    <p class="txt">Example7</p>
    <p class="txt">Example8</p>
    <p class="txt">Example9</p>
    <p class="txt">Example1</p>
    <p class="txt">Example2</p>
    <p class="txt">Example3</p>
    <p class="txt">Example4</p>
    <p class="txt">Example5</p>
    <p class="txt">Example6</p>
    <p class="txt">Example7</p>
    <p class="txt">Example8</p>
    <p class="txt">Example9</p>
    <p class="txt">Example1</p>
    <p class="txt">Example2</p>
    <p class="txt">Example3</p>
    <p class="txt">Example4</p>
    <p class="txt">Example5</p>
    <p class="txt">Example6</p>
    <p class="txt">Example7</p>
    <p class="txt">Example8</p>
    <p class="txt">Example9</p>
    <p class="txt">Example3</p>
    <p class="txt">Example4</p>
    <p class="txt">Example5</p>
    <p class="txt">Example6</p>
    <p class="txt">Example7</p>
    <p class="txt">Example8</p>
    <p class="txt">Example9</p>
    <p class="txt">Example1</p>
    <p class="txt">Example2</p>
    <p class="txt">Example3</p>
    <p class="txt">Example4</p>
    <p class="txt">Example5</p>
    <p class="txt">Example6</p>
    <p class="txt">Example7</p>
    <p class="txt">Example8</p>
    <p class="txt">Example9</p>
    <p class="txt">Example1</p>
    <p class="txt">Example2</p>
    <p class="txt">Example3</p>
    <p class="txt">Example4</p>
    <p class="txt">Example5</p>
    <p class="txt">Example6</p>
    <p class="txt">Example7</p>
    <p class="txt">Example8</p>
    <p class="txt">Example9</p>
    <p class="txt">Example1</p>
    <p class="txt">Example2</p>
    <p class="txt">Example3</p>
    <p class="txt">Example4</p>
    <p class="txt">Example5</p>
    <p class="txt">Example6</p>
    <p class="txt">Example7</p>
    <p class="txt">Example8</p>
    <p class="txt">Example9</p>
    <p class="txt">Example3</p>
    <p class="txt">Example4</p>
    <p class="txt">Example5</p>
    <p class="txt">Example6</p>
    <p class="txt">Example7</p>
    <p class="txt">Example8</p>
    <p class="txt">Example9</p>
    <p class="txt">Example1</p>
    <p class="txt">Example2</p>
    <p class="txt">Example3</p>
    <p class="txt">Example4</p>
    <p class="txt">Example5</p>
    <p class="txt">Example6</p>
    <p class="txt">Example7</p>
    <p class="txt">Example8</p>
    <p class="txt">Example9</p>
    <p class="txt">Example1</p>
    <p class="txt">Example2</p>
    <p class="txt">Example3</p>
    <p class="txt">Example4</p>
    <p class="txt">Example5</p>
    <p class="txt">Example6</p>
    <p class="txt">Example7</p>
    <p class="txt">Example8</p>
    <p class="txt">Example9</p>
    <p class="txt">Example1</p>
    <p class="txt">Example2</p>
    <p class="txt">Example3</p>
    <p class="txt">Example4</p>
    <p class="txt">Example5</p>
    <p class="txt">Example6</p>
    <p class="txt">Example7</p>
    <p class="txt">Example8</p>
    <p class="txt">Example9</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>




yes but when I scroll down the background should scroll too along with the content, when the background image is over, it should scroll only the content

I'm not sure I understood what you meant. Try putting in .background_container {} background-attachment: fixed;
Is this what you meant?

When I open this page and scroll down it just gets white but it should be the lower visible part of the PNG, so it should scroll down the content and the background at the same time at the end of the background it should stay at the bottom of background (just stop scrolling it) but keep scrolling the content.

You want content to get scrolled with image until image end is reached
.After image reaches its end you want your content to scroll continuously.
If above is your requirement then this will resolve your issue.
Add background-image to your container, then add background-repeat: no-repeat; and finally added desired size to image with background-size: 50%;. Check below code with output for better understanding. Thank You.


const dummyData = [...Array(1000)];
const mappedData = dummyData.map((item,index) => `<h1>${index}</h1>`);

document.querySelector(".mainBackground").innerHTML = mappedData.join('')
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mainBackground{
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1718308055947-2f3d8d5ea983?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=M3wzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE3MjE2MzE5MzF8&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=85');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50%;
}
<div class="mainBackground">
</div>



If your need is different then add it's image or example.

Thank you for response! Yes, I think it's really close to what I want. I just want it to stop scrolling the background when it reaches its end so we cannot see the white area under the background, but the content should scroll down anyway.



body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.background_container {
  background-color: #444444;
  background-image: url("https://i.sstatic.net/mL8LVRMD.png");
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  position: absolute;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="background_container">

  </div>

  <p class="txt"> Example1 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example2 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example3 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example4 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example5 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example6 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example7 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example8 </p>
  <p class="txt"> Example9 </p>


</body>

</html>




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
